# Use percent difference from two dataframes and apply to third

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, apply

I have 3 datasets:

```
df1
group             Int            var_a
  100     0.044211088     -0.012787829
  200    -0.047100911      0.077978254
  300     0.038150455     -0.007357197
  400     0.040368393     -0.008928011
  500     0.062128815     -0.030815453
  600     0.004291613      0.026521099

df2
          Int           var_a
1   0.9701036     0.001630575

df3
                                   Int            var_a
standardized coefficient   0.918654358     -0.001624649
```

`df1` are the residuals of the values of `df2`. So for example, for `group 100` in column `Int`, the value is 0.044 greater than 0.970 from df2 `Int`. This would be equivalent to saying this is a 4.56% increase. I want to calculate the percent difference from each column's `df2` with it's respective column from df1.

I then want to apply that percent increase or decrease for each value with `df3` to get an equivalent coefficient for each group.

More in-depth:

1) Take Percentage difference between df1 and df2:

```
group      int       var_a
  100    4.56%    -784.25%
  200   -4.86%    4782.25%
  300    3.93%    -451.20%
  400    4.16%    -547.54%
  500    6.40%   -1889.85%
  600    0.44%    1626.49%
```

Then apply this percentage difference from the table above to it's respective columns in df3 to get this final result:

```
group           int           var_a
  100    0.96052072     0.011116705
  200   0.874051434    -0.079319507
  300   0.954781512      0.00570581
  400   0.956881822     0.007270915
  500   0.977488184     0.029078811
  600   0.922718366    -0.028049362
```

Let me know if this makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did that does what you need?

```
df1$Int <- df3$Int*(1+((df2$Int+df1$Int)/df2$Int)-1)
df1$Var_a <- df3$Var_a*(1+((df2$Var_a+df1$Var_a)/df2$Var_a)-1)
```

**EDIT**

```
fun1 <- function(df1,df2,df3){

  df1 <- df3*(1+((df2+df1)/df2)-1)


  outdata<-data.frame(df1)
  return(outdata)
}
```

for flexibility change the index range after the split fct

```
df.new <- sapply(split(df1[,2:3], rownames(df1)), fun1, df2=df2,df3=df3)

df.new <- cbind(df1$group, data.frame(matrix(unlist(df.new), nrow=nrow(df1), byrow=T)))

colnames(df.new) <- colnames(df1)
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this by indexes? It's not always going to be the same number of columns

Comment: can you elaborate? in df1?

Comment: I basically want to transfer the random effects based on a different model (df3). So df2 shows the coefficients and df1 is the residuals based on that. I want to take that percentage difference and apply it to a different model (df3) and get new coefficients

Comment: sorry I actually don't get it maybe you can extend your examples

Comment: I just edited the question to extend the example, let me know if this makes more sense! Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to write this though so that it doesn't matter how many variables I have? So let's say I have 100 variables, then I would have to hardcode it using your answer.

Comment: Maybe like a for-loop by column indexes so it will apply this formula to each matching column?

Comment: The order will always match in each dataframe, so if it's possible to do it by indexing then that would be perfect because I'm not always going to know the column name. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Thanks! I'm away from my computer for the weekend but will see if this works tomorrow night. Appreciate the help

Comment: Thanks. I think it may have worked. How would you change it to a dataframe in the same format as my final output instead of a list?

Comment: sorry for all the questions, could you not make the numbers hardcoded for nrow(6)? It's going to be many more rows since this is just a sample dataset.